# Как создать splash screen в visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

Есть две формы: одна - главная рабочая область, вторая - splash screen. 
Код такой(основные функции: таймер и конструктор главной формы):

Конструктор главной формы:

```
  this->Hide();
    SimpleReplacment::SplashScreen^ splashScreen = gcnew SimpleReplacment::SplashScreen();
    splashScreen->Show();
    if (splashScreen->Opacity <= 0) {
        delete splashScreen;
        this->Show();
    }
```

Таймер splash screen:

```
    this->Opacity -= 0.05;
if (this->Opacity <= 0) {
    timer_loading->Enabled = false;
    this->Enabled = false;
    this->Close();
}
```

Проблема в том, что при загрузке главной формы она появляется сразу, т.к. условие одноразовое, но если я сделаю цикл поверх блока кода с условием, то не будет выполняться код побочной формы. 
Что нужно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему Вы не открываете сразу splash screen при запуске приложения, которая (по завершению таймера...) откроет главную форму?
Splash screen:

```
    this->Opacity -= 0.05;
if (this->Opacity <= 0) {
    timer_loading->Enabled = false;
    MainForm->Show(); // like this
    this->Enabled = false;
    this->Close();
}
```

А в настройках проекта указать, чтобы запуск был с другой формы.